# How to write javadoc @deprecated method with parameters @link

Tags: java, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

```
/**
 * @deprecated As of release 4.1, replaced by {@link com.github.noraui.application.steps.WaitSteps#waitVisibilityOf(String, List<GherkinStepCondition>)}
 *             
 *  
 */
@Deprecated
public void checkElementVisible(String pageElement, List<GherkinStepCondition> conditions) throws 
FailureException, TechnicalException {
    String page = pageElement.split("-")[0];
    String elementName = pageElement.split("-")[1];
    checkElementVisible(Page.getInstance(page).getPageElementByKey('-' + elementName), true);
}
```

I have this error:

```
warning - Tag @link:illegal character: "60" in "com.github.noraui.application.steps.WaitSteps#waitInvisibilityOf(String, List<GherkinStepCondition>)"
warning - Tag @link:illegal character: "62" in "com.github.noraui.application.steps.WaitSteps#waitInvisibilityOf(String, List<GherkinStepCondition>)"
```

So I try without parameters:

```
@deprecated As of release 4.1, replaced by {@link com.github.noraui.application.steps.WaitSteps#waitVisibilityOf()}
```

I have this error:

```
warning - Tag @link: can't find waitInvisibilityOf() in com.github.noraui.application.steps.WaitSteps
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the code below:

```
/**
 * @deprecated As of release 4.1, replaced by {@link com.github.noraui.application.steps.WaitSteps#waitVisibilityOf(String, List)}
 */
```

So that there is no parametrisation for `List` interface